# Add an id in Knockout

Tags: javascript, mvvm, view, knockout.js, model

I have an observableArray

```
self.workouts = ko.observableArray([
    {name: "Chest/Biceps", exercises:self.exercises1},
    {name: "Back/Triceps", exercises:self.exercises2},
    {name: "Legs/Shoulders", exercises:self.exercises3},
    ]);
```

`exercises1` looks like this:

```
self.exercises1 = ko.observableArray([
    {name: "bench press", sets:self.sets},
    {name: "machine chest press", sets:self.sets1},
    {name: "standing biceps curl", sets:self.sets2},
    {name: "machine biceps curl", sets:self.sets3}
]);
```

What I want is to add a unique `id` to each object in `exercises1` and then bind it in my View. I've tried to use attr binding, but without success.

My View looks like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: workouts">
        <li class="name"><a class="name" data-bind="text:name"></a>
            <ul class="hhide" data-bind="foreach: exercises">
                <li class="name_ex"><a data-bind="text:name"></a>
                <div class="hhide">
                    <input id ="weight" type="text" placeholder="weight(kg)">
                    <span id="append">x</span>
                    <input id ="reps" type="text" placeholder="reps">
                    <button id="sets" data-bind="click: $root.addSet">Add set</button>
                    <div data-bind="foreach: sets">
                        <div id="sets" class="remove" data-bind="click: $root.removeSet">delete</div>
                        <div data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: name, click: edit"></div>
                        <input data-bind="visible: editing, value: name, hasFocus: editing" />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>       
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?  (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U7EFz/4/)

html:

```
<div class="content">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: workouts">
        <li class="name"><a class="name" data-bind="text:name"></a>
            <ul class="hhide" data-bind="foreach: exercises">
                <li class="name_ex">
                    <a data-bind="text:name, attr:{id:uniqueId}"></a>                                                                                               
                    | uniqueId:
                    <span data-bind="text:uniqueId"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>       
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
var VM = function(){
    var self = this;
    var idCounter = 0;
    self.getId = function(){        
        return "id" + (++idCounter);
    }

    self.exercises1 = ko.observableArray([
        {name: "bench press", uniqueId:"id1"},
        {name: "machine chest press", uniqueId:"id2"},
        {name: "standing biceps curl", uniqueId:"id3"},
        {name: "machine biceps curl", uniqueId:"id4"}
    ]);    

    self.workouts = ko.observableArray([
        {name: "Chest/Biceps", exercises:self.exercises1},
        {name: "Back/Triceps", exercises:self.exercises1},
        {name: "Legs/Shoulders", exercises:self.exercises1},
        ]);      
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM())
```

Comment: Yes, but It's not so nice to use random Id for each exercise. I want to have the ability to set specific id's. Like:
`{name: "bench press", id: "ex1"},
{name: "machine chest press", "ex2"}` and so on.

Comment: Updated with an Id counter. Something like this?

Comment: Well, it seems to be a solution, but isn't it possible to add an Id like I did with each `name`? Like write myself an Id into each exercise and not generate it from a function?

Comment: Thanks for reply. In your example it works, in my code it doesn't. Maybe it's because I use it this way:
{name: "bench press", uniqueId:"1", sets:self.sets}.

Comment: It should work, are you getting any errors in the console? What if you remove self.sets?

Comment: Sorry. It's working now) Quite a dumb question, but it helped me to find out what was wrong) Thanks!